# How do I serve thousands of websites with Amazon S3 or CloudFront?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

We're building a website editor - like Wix, Webflow etc. Users can create their websites, and choose to deploy them - and add their own custom domain to it.

For example -

An user created a website and wants it to be deployed to https://client1.com

The static files for that entire website is being stored in a **subfolder** of a bucket called **all-sites**. This bucket will have subfolders, each one corresponding to a different website.

For example, the bucket **all-sites** will have these sub-folders -

```
/client1-site
/client2-site
/client3-site
```

and each one of these folders will have their static website content/resources -

```
/client1.com
..index.html
..js/
....script.js
..img/
....img.png
```

How do I ask users to add A/CNAME records to their domain, that points exactly to these subfolders? Or what should my server's endpoint do to serve all these websites, while loading content for each website independently, also making sure the websites are being served over HTTPS?

Currently I have come up with a couple of approaches, but none of them are good -

1. Instead of saving files to s3, save it to my server's storage, and return files from the server - which is very easy but will have problems with SSL certificates.
2. Add a cloudfront distribution for that bucket, and serve sites - https://xyz.cloudfront.net/site-id/index.html etc. But how do I link that to a client's url?

Answer (score 0):

Your CloudFront idea sounds best to me as you would gain some extra advantages, key among them enabling caching on different regions (which might not be advisable if using APIs though).

I guess at this point you would have to ask the customer to add a CNAME record pointing towards his corresponding CloudFront distribution domain name (typically something like XXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. That means, I'll have to create a distribution for each of the client? And the current limit of cloudfront distributions is 250. What if I wish to exceed that limit?

Comment: you can a: ask aws to increase the limit, or better yet, create an account for each client and deploy the distribution to the client's account

Comment: @SathyajithBhat We can't manually create thousands of AWS accounts. We want to manage all of that ourselves. How do sites like wix/webflow handle this?

Comment: If you are planning for thousands of customers, the multi-account strategy is the one that will scale the best. Create an organization in your main account, and add each customer as a child account. You can use something like [AWS Account Factory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/controltower/latest/userguide/account-factory.html) combined with an Infrastructure as Code (Terraform, CloudFormation, etc) combined with some SDK calls to manage the infrastructure overhead.